# How to specifically print out a word without losing its counted length

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with my code. I have .csv file named test.csv which contains 3 sentences and a code that counts each word on my sentence, it determines the number of the first letter and the last but when i tried the for loop below, it counts the specific words but only the specific word, it didn't count the rest of the sentences. I want to print out a specific word while their number of position remains.

```
with open("test.csv") as e:
    text = e.read()

newtext = text.split()
words = '' 

currCount = 0 


for words in newtext:

    toAdd = len(words)
    if words == 'is':
        print ("("+str(currCount)+","+str(currCount+toAdd)+")"+ words)
    elif words != 'is':
        continue

    currCount+= toAdd+1

    if words is ".":
        currCount = 0
```

This is the sentence inside of "test.csv".

```
my name is bob .
bob is my name .
my real name is lob .
```

Output:

```
Output                                   What i want
(0,2)is                                  (8,10)is
(3,5)is                                  (4,6)is
(6,8)is                                  (13,15)is
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this part:

```
elif words != 'is':
    continue
```

This will *skip* everything after that -- in particular the part that increments `currCount` -- and continue directly with the next iteration of the loop. You probably meant "in this case, do nothing". If you want to make this explicit, you can use `pass` instead of `continue`. Also note that the `elif` is redundant as the condition is exactly the inverse of the first condition, and you can just use `else`.

But in fact you could just as well drop those two lines entirely.

Alternatively, you could use a regular expression to find the word and it's position:

```
import re
with open("corpus.txt") as e:
    for line in e:
        for group in re.finditer(r"\bis\b", line):
            print(group.group(), group.span())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code:

```
def FindPosition(String,word):
    return ([(a.start(), a.end()) for a in list(re.finditer(word, String))])

import re
aString = 'my name is bob.\nbob is my name.\nmy real name is lob .'
word = "is"
NewText = aString.split("\n")

for line in NewText:
    Match_List = FindPosition(line,word)
    if Match_List:
        for pos in Match_List:
            print(pos," ",word)
```

Output:

```
(8, 10)   is
(4, 6)   is
(13, 15)   is
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I suggested two hours ago. Also, `if Match_List` does not do what you think it does; a generator is always truthy, even if empty.